# How to debug a Receive and Send ports in BizTalk Admin Console?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have couple of Receive and Send ports, they are working fine except one of them.

So do we have any way by which I can debug or look at the sequence in which the ports are executed and get the details as to why that particular port is not working?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please?

The mose common Port issues are typically no subscribers found - if you are using Direct Bound ports (messagebox), a common way to debug these is to compare a suspended message with the filters set on the available subscriptions (New Query, Search for Equals Subscriptions) with the promoted properties on the failed message itself. 

AFAIK there is no guarantee on the order in which subscriptions are fired, this is generally undesirable as publish-subscribe should be as loosely coupled as possible (and subscribers oblivious of other listeners)

Answer (score 1):

Turn on tracking on your orchestration. In the management console group hub look at 'tracked message events'. You can also view the progress within an orchestration. Right click on an orchestration tracking event and you can find orchestration debugger there.